# Extract certain words from predefined sentence using regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I have seemingly simple task, but I have no experience with regular expressions.
I have to parse SMS body with predefined message text, to get out certain information.
Here is one example:

> Täname! {FirstName} {LastName} isikukoodiga {PersonCode} on sõlminud EMT Reisikindlustuse lepingu numbriga {PolicyNumber}, mis kehtib alates {CoverStartDate} kell {CoverStartTime} kuni {CoverEndDate} kell {CoverEndTime} (Eesti aja järgi). Hind: {PremiumEur} eurot. Tutvu tingimustega ({Terms})  http://emt.ee/kindlustus. Kahjukäsitluse number +3727330700.

I have to parse out everything that is in curly braces.

I came up with something like this in Java:

```
public static final String REGEX_CONFIRMATION = "Täname! (.*) (.*) isikukoodiga (.*) on sõlminud EMT Reisikindlustuse lepingu numbriga (.*), mis kehtib alates (.*) kell (.*) kuni (.*) kell (.*) \\(Eesti aja järgi\\). Hind: (.*) eurot. Tutvu tingimustega \\((.*)\\) http://emt.ee/kindlustus. Kahjukäsitluse number \\+3727330700.";
```

But it parses out only following groups:

> {MARIS}, {PLOTS}, {17204046521}, {22414152}, {01.10.2002}, {13:07},
>   {02.10.2002}, {23:59}.

As you can see `{Terms}` is missing. And I can't seem to figure out where is the problem?

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that You have different string, that what you showed us. Instead {FirstName} you have something like MARIS?

Answer (score 0):

how about using this pattern?

```
\{.*?\}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it make more sense to simply use

```
\{[^{}]*\}
```

as your regex? In a string, you would need to write that as

```
"\\{[^{}]*\\}"
```

**Explanation:**

```
\{      # Match an opening brace
[^{}]*  # Match any number of characters except braces
\}      # Match a closing brace
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Regular-Expressions/Findallmatches.htm

along with the following regex

```
\{(.*?)\}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems correct to me. Use the DOTALL (and in other cases maybe MULTILINE) options. DOTALL can be added as `"(?s)Täname!..."`. Then the `".*"` also maps newline chars.

As the prior matches were found this might be it.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work, when You include brackets into your {TERMS} part?
Instead of:

```
String regex = "...Tutvu tingimustega \\((.*)\\) http://emt.ee/kindlustus. ...";
```

You could try:

```
String regex = "...Tutvu tingimustega (.*) http://emt.ee/kindlustus. ...";
```

OR depending on, what You have in {TERMS} string, You could change _**.***_ to _**[^)]***_
This way you would find zero to N chars that are not ending bracket.